# How can I show the positive and negative comments for a same post separately?

Tags: posts, comments

I am working on a page in which the user will be able to choose whether he/she wants to see the positive feedback or the negative ones only.

Whenever any user opens a post and moves over his cursor over the content it will have a hover effect, with positive comments on one half of the content and negative comments on the other half. There will be no comments shown below initially.

If the user clicks over the positive hover section then all the positive comments will be shown at the bottom of the page (it will not redirect the user to any other page) and he will also be allowed to post his own too.

Is it possible to do? Can anyone give me any hint how can I do such a thing?

I just haven't yet started coding that, I am just not getting how can it be done.

Comment: Hi Suraj, welcome to WPSE. Ideally questions here should show us the code you are implementing so we can specifically help you with what you're getting stuck on. People here are generally reluctant to write it all for you :) Could you edit your post to explain where you've got to so far, and what exactly you're finding difficult to implement?

Comment: Thanks for your review! Actually I am kind of new to WordPress theme development and this feature is the only thing I am not able to get ideas about implementing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, comments ( if i remember correct and nothing has changed from v4 ) are custom post types, so u can add post_meta to it, like `response` => `true` ( positive ) or `false` ( negative ).

Then u could make custom query ( `WP_Comment_Query` ) to get comments for certain post with meta parametrs ( ak. `Custom Field Parameters` )

You would need 2 queries, 1 returning positive, 2-nd - negative comments..

Everything othere depends on you'r design..

Ah yes. When posting a comment you woud need to make some field to save post meta whanever it is positive or negative...

***Elaborating my answer:***

Ok, for ex. on the front-end ( FE ) u have form, witch submits a comment to a certain post. You would need ( if u don't have already ) some field that will determine whathere it's "good" or "bad" comment. Lets call these field `response` ( and lets imagine that it's radio button with 2 choices: `good` and `bad` as values ).

Then, when user submits form he must select one of the radio buttons and on a php side ( back-end ) you'll have his answer as `(string) $_POST['response']`.
so, now u have a variable `$response` wich contains 1 of radio button values.

Next u would need to insert new comment into database ( for ex. using `wp_insert_comment` function ) it will return new comment ID.

Next u would need to store your `response` to these comment using `add_comment_meta` function passing new comment ID, uniqeue name representing `response` key in database ( for ex.: `_response` ) and a value ( $response ) ( last param - unique, better to be true )...

So, now you have comment in database, u have comment meta in database.

Now u can make a query to database to get all comments for some post/page, it would looke like these:

```
<?php
$args = array(
   'post_id' => get_the_id(), // or if u have some variable u could use it to get all comments from post/page
   'meta_key' => '_response', // from add_comment_meta - unique name representing key in database
   'meta_value' => 'good' // "good" or "bad" or whatever u desire to be
);

// The Query
$comments_query = new WP_Comment_Query;
$comments = $comments_query->query( $args );

// Comment Loop
if ( $comments ) {
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) {
        $response = get_comment_meta( $comment->comment_ID, '_response', true ); // store response to $response variable for later use
        echo '<p>' . $comment->comment_content . '. <span>These comment is:' . $response . '</span></p>'; // the output of a comment
    }
} else {
    echo 'No comments found.';
}
?>
```

that way u can get 2 different queryies, 1 with good comments 2-nd with bad comments and echo them in different places on the page ( left side, right side ).

Basicaly it's the same as with CPT and get_post_meta - only comments...
If u can think how to query CPT with certain meta value - u can do it with comment to..

Related links:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Comment_Query
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_comment_meta

If u steel have some questions feel free to ask..

Comment: I was thinking about adding categories to the comments.

Comment: Maikal thanks for your help! Can you elaborate what you just said.

Comment: you would likely want to create a custom `comments.php` template and/or callback for the comments display too.

Comment: suraj kumar, i'v updated my answer, hope these will be more clear.